# Pass choices from views to form

Tags: python, django, forms, view, choicefield

I use the form `Bannerform` to create new `Banner` object trough the `add_banner` views (and template). I use the class `Options` to definite which `affiliation` objects to permit in the form `Bannerform` (`affiliation` field).

I'm trying to pass choices from the views to the form but it give me ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My code worked when `new_affiliation` was a ForeignKey but now I need more values. I think I must definite 'choices' in the `views` or I will have problem on the first migration (it appear to call the database tables from the `models.py` but not from the `views.py`, so if I put `Options.objects.get(id=1)` on the `models.py` it give error because the tables don't exist yet).

My `form.py`:

```
from django import forms
from core.models import Options, Banner, Affiliation #somethings other

class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    affiliation = forms.ChoiceField('choices')
    #affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField('choices') #same error
    class Meta:
        model = Banner
        exclude = (#some fields)
```

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class Options(models.Model):
    new_affiliation = models.ManyToManyField('Affiliation')
    #new_affiliation = models.ForeignKey('Affiliation') #this worked (with some changes in views)

class Affiliation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class Banner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    affiliation = models.ForeignKey(Affiliation)
```

My `views.py`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code here
    else:
        options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
        print(options.new_affiliation.all()) #controll
        choices = options.new_affiliation.all()
        print(choices) #controll
        form = BannerForm(choices, initial={            
            #some code regarding other fields
            })       
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

My `add_banner.html`:

```
<form role="form" id="banner_form" enctype="multipart/form-data "method="post" action="../add_banner/">

  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}      
    {{ field.help_text }}
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Updated. I changed only `views.py`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code here
    else:
        options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
        print(options.new_affiliation.all()) #controll
        choices = tuple(options.new_affiliation.all())
        print(choices) #controll
        form = BannerForm(choices, initial={            
            #some code regarding other fields
            })       
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

But still give error.

Update 2. If I pass choices directly from form.py it works:
My `views.py`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code here
    else:
        form = BannerForm(request.POST or None, initial={
            #some code regarding other fields
            })
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
    choices = options.new_affiliation.all()
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(choices)
```

Unluckly this give problems on the first migration (see above).

I'm trying to pass choices using some init method...

My `forms.py`:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    affiliation = forms.ModelChoiceField(choices)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
        choices = options.new_affiliation.all()
        #choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        super(RegentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['affiliation'] = choices
```

but it say that choices is not definite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see here, it looks like you are getting an error "too many values to unpack" because you are not sending "choices" as the correct type. A ChoiceField takes choices only as a tuple, as seen in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices) for models. If you are looking to define choices based on a QuerySet, you'll have to convert it into a tuple which can be interpreted as valid "choices". In one of my projects for example, I needed to prepare a set of years as a tuple so that I could allow users to select from a list of pre-determined years. I specified the following function to do this:

```
def years():
    response = []
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    for i in range(1900, now.year + 1):
        response.append([i, str(i)])
    return tuple(response)
```

Since tuples are meant to be immutable, it usually isn't a good idea to cast them, just based on principle. However, in this case it seems necessary as a measure to declare that you are okay with the possible variability with these statements.

In your specific situation, you might consider doing something like this:

```
choices = tuple(options.new_affiliation.all().values())
```

I have not tested this code, and I frankly am not completely familiar with your project and may be mistaken in some part of this response. As a result, it may require further tweaking, but give it a try. Based on your error, this is definitely where the program is breaking currently. Update here if you make any progress.

Comment: It give an error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'. 
Error during template rendering. The error is on the {{ hidden }} row.
 Maybe can help to know that my 
choices = options.new_affiliation.all() 
printed is: 
[<Affiliation: Red>, <Affiliation: Black>], 
Your 
choices = tuple(options.new_affiliation.all().values()) 
printed is: 
({'id': 1, 'name': 'Red'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Black'}). 
Here the last row of the error http://dpaste.com/30AY564

Comment: @fabio You may want to send it in a different format then, in order for it to be readable without any keywords. You could do something like this: choices = tuple(options.new_affiliation.all().get('name').values()) This will retrieve only the names like (('Black'), ('Red'))  --  Based on the snippets here it is still a little bit tough to determine exactly what is going on, so try messing around with the results a bit more and post back with more information. I can try some of this code in my own IDE to see if it produces a desirable result.

Comment: I don't know what informations give you... I edited my first post adding somethings. Maybe the problem is that it take choices like a field and it try to render it on the template... maybe we should pass choice in some __init__ metod?

Comment: Here is how it is supposed to work: 1) at begin the database don't exist. 2) I create the database with the first migration 3) I populate the database with a script. I create some affiliation objects. 4) I create one and only one options object. In the new_affilation fields I chose only some affiliation objects 5) the users can create a banner chosing only one affiliation between the ones I selected for them in pass4 6) sometime i will modify the option object to permit different affilations in new banner.  I hope this clarify

Answer (score 2):

Done!

My `form.py`:

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=32, label='Nome')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        options = Options.objects.get(id=1)
        choices = options.new_affiliation.all()
        super(BannerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['affiliation'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(choices)
        self.fields['affiliation'].initial = choices

    class Meta:
        model = Banner
```

My `views.py`:

```
def add_banner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #some code here
    else:
        form = BannerForm(request.POST or None, initial={
        #some code here
            })
    return render(request, 'core/add_banner.html', {'form': form})
```

Thank you

Comment: Cool, you got it working. Yes, the init method was a good addition. You needed to process the information more before rendering. Looks good